# Change value of the parent property in an inherited Angular service

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9.
I have Service A and Service B that extends the Service A.
In service A I have a property and I want to change the value of this property from service B.
I see that it does not change in the Father but only in the Son.

In service B I call `super.editProperty()` and in service A I have:

```
editProperty() { this.property = 'content' }
```

Now in service B, I have the property updated but not in Service A.
I have a simple example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gcsxq

Is it aspected behavior? How can I make it change in the Service A?

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting two separate instances of a service. Each instance will have its own set of fields.
If you want to prevent code from reaching `PadreService`'s internal state declare it as an abstract class and remove
`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})`

Comment: I want to change the property in PadreService

Comment: @Alessandro, then create an instance of PadreService and change it.

Comment: Yes, this works. Inherit from Service A, but remove the @injectable (from A).  This means, service B inherits A and any properties set in B also set in A.